# Optimal data structure and algorithm for getting the k'th element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm given a set of n elements.
Is there a data structure with a build time (pre processing) of O(n).
and from then on can answer queries to get the k'th largest element in O(k)?
Is there anything better than O(k)?

Comment: Why not just sort the array(of unique elements) in decreasing order? You could answer each query to get `k`th largest in O(1) time.

Comment: because sorting will take at least O(nlog(n)) time of pre processing.

Comment: The problem is called selection: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm. A simple way is to use a heap but there are more efficient ways.

Comment: @elihar Ok, but how is the nature of the dataset? If there is only a certain range of numbers like from `1` to `10000` then you could declare an array of size `10000` and assign values. So, pre-processing is done in `O(1)` time(since it doesn't grow with input) and even answering queries would be `O(1)`. Otherwise, you could go with heaps but answering queries would be `O(k * log(n))` I suppose.

Comment: There are no assumptions about the nature of the set.

Comment: I think after building a heap in O(n) you could search for the kth largest object in O(k log(k)) if you traverse it in a best-first manner (It should be possible to show that the priority queue for the best-first traversal has at most size O(k)). I can work out the details if this is good enough for you.

Comment: not sure I understand, how it is O(k)?
I know it should be O(klog(k)).
If you can elaborate it would be great.

Comment: As I said the search would be O(k log(k)). I spared the details because you were explicitly asking for O(k). However, in case you are looking for the fastest possible solution that someone comes up I offered to sketch out the details.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-O-k-complexity-for-finding-k-th-largest-element-in-a-max-heap

Comment: @juvian these answers seem to be incomplete/strange. The first one is what I proposed but forgets the runtime of the additional heap. The second answer compares nodes with some x and returns a boolean...

Comment: I'm almost certain these answers are wrong...

Comment: maybe https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540183710308

Comment: found this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944322/algorithm-how-to-find-the-kth-element-in-ok-and-with-build-on
But I'm not sure that I quite understood how it works, or why it is O(k)?

Comment: @elihar it relies on the average case of quickselect being O(n). The list you apply quickselect will have at most k elements

Answer (score 3):

Sketching out my comment for a `O(n)` build time and `O(k log k)` search time for the kth largest element.

Preprocessing is just building a heap `h` which can be done in `O(n)`

Then during query time you have to use an additional priority queue `q` where elements are ordered by value (descending). The algorithm works as follows:

- start by putting the root node of `h` into `q`
- now repeat `k` times: remove the head of `q` and put the children of this element (according to `h`) in `q`
- the last element removed is your kth largest element

Removing an element from `q` (which is itself a heap) is O(|q|). In each step `q` will grow by 1 element. After `k-1` steps it will have a size of `k`.  Thus this algorithm runs in **O(k log k)**